# apt-get update with https sources broken

Tags: apt, raspbian, https

When I try to run `apt-get update` I get the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
/usr/lib/apt/methods/https: error while loading shared libraries: libnett▒d.sm.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https did not start correctly
```

When I disable all HTTPS sources (docker, gitlab-runner), apt-get runs fine and I am able to install packages.
Google fails to find a library named `libnett*d.sm.4`.

I'm running raspbian on a RaspberryPi 3:

```
$ cat /etc/*release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

I have tried reinstalling `apt-transport-https`.

I have also noticed: `ping6` doesn't work as well (same library). Of course I have tried disabling IPv6.

**Update**:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

---

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
deb [arch=armhf] https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo raspbian-jessie main


deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
# deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui


# this file was generated by packages.gitlab.com for
# the repository at https://packages.gitlab.com/runner/gitlab-ci-multi-runner
# deb https://packages.gitlab.com/runner/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/raspbian/ jessie main
# deb-src https://packages.gitlab.com/runner/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/raspbian/ jessie main
```

I disabled the sources for `gitlab-runner` completely, `docker` is active in the output - if comment that line out as well, `apt-get update` runs fine as *all* active sources use `http`.

Comment: Welcome to U&L please add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like disk corruption; it should be looking for `libnettle.so.4`.

To fix this particular issue, I suspect you should reinstall `libcurl3-gnutls`:

```
apt-get --reinstall install libcurl3-gnutls
```

(as `root`).

This may not be the culprit though; to identify other corrupted files (at least, those installed from packages), you can use `debsums`:

```
debsums -c
```

(after installing it if necessary using `apt-get install debsums`). You should reinstall any packages flagged by `debsums -c`.

The `debsums` manpage gives this handy command to reinstall affected packages:

```
apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -S $(debsums -c) | cut -d : -f 1 | sort -u)
```

Comment: The raspberry has known issues with data corruption when turning it off. Over time the card also will also not be that reliable.

Comment: Reinstalling `libcur3-gnutls` didn't help. I also cleared the cache with `apt-get clean` before reinstalling to make sure it downloads a fresh copy.

Comment: Thanks @RuiFRibeiro, that suggests Raspberry Pi owners should run `debsums -c` regularly! The `debsums` package installs cronjobs, so if `cron` or `anacron` is set up and email is working then users should be warned — that's  alot of ifs though.

Comment: @mgansler what does `debsums -c` say?

Comment: debsum -c reported two files: `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libhogweed.so.2.5` and `/usr/share/perl5/Module/Build/Base.pm`, reinstalling the packages now.

Comment: OK, `libhogweed` would explain it too, it also depends on `libnettle`.

Comment: Reinstallation is complete, `apt-get update` is working again, thanks! Also thanks for telling me about `debsum`, I will run that regularly now.

Comment: For completeness: I used `dpkg-query -S <file>` to find out to which package(s) the files listed by `debsum -c` belong.